# Php pagination in dropdownlist

Tags: php, jquery

I have Dynamic Dropdownlist and php pagination. I want to create a dropdown for page number. Instead of having normal pagination (Prev 1-2-3 Next), I want those in a dropdown.
Something like in admin pages where the dropdown menu helps you to move quickly to the desired page.

Like this in Phpmyadmin

[image]

And this is my code right row

Firstpage

```
<script>
function showUser(str,ids) {
    var $txtHint = $('#txtHint');
    if (str=="" || ids=="") {
        $txtHint.html('');
        return;
    }
    $txtHint.load('app_list.php?q='+str+'&id='+ids) 
}

</script>
```

Secondpage

```
$id = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["q"]);
$id2 = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET["id"]);
if (isset($_GET['id'])) { 
    $id2 = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET['id']); 
} else { 
    $id2 = 1;
} 
$itemsPerPage = 100; 
$lastPage = ceil($nr / $itemsPerPage);
if ($id2 < 1) { 
    $id2 = 1; 
} else if ($id2 > $lastPage) { 
    $id2 = $lastPage; 
} 

$centerPages = "";
$sub1 = $id2 - 1;
$sub2 = $id2 - 2;
$add1 = $id2 + 1;
$add2 = $id2 + 2;
if ($id2 == 1) {

    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $id2 . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $add1 .'")>' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($id2 == $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $sub1 .'")>' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $id2 . '</span> &nbsp;';
} else if ($id2 > 2 && $id2 < ($lastPage - 1)) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $sub2 .'")>' . $sub2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $sub1 .'")>' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $id2 . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $add1 .'")>' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $add2 .'")>' . $add2 . '</a> &nbsp;';
} else if ($id2 > 1 && $id2 < $lastPage) {
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $sub1 .'")>' . $sub1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <span class="pagNumActive">' . $id2 . '</span> &nbsp;';
    $centerPages .= '&nbsp; <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $add1 .'")>' . $add1 . '</a> &nbsp;';
}

$limit = 'LIMIT ' .($id2 - 1) * $itemsPerPage .',' .$itemsPerPage; 

//query

$paginationDisplay = "";
if ($lastPage != "1"){
    $paginationDisplay .= 'Page <strong>' . $id2 . '</strong> of ' . $lastPage. '&nbsp;  &nbsp;  &nbsp; ';
    if ($id2 != 1) {
        $previous = $id2 - 1;
        //$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="next?id=' . $previous . '"> Back</a> ';
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $previous .'")> Back</a> ';
    }                                               
    $paginationDisplay .= '<span class="paginationNumbers">' . $centerPages . '</span>';
    if ($id2 != $lastPage) {
        $nextPage = $id2 + 1;
        $paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="#" onclick=showUser(str="'. $id .'",ids="'. $nextPage .'")> Next</a> ';
        //$paginationDisplay .=  '&nbsp;  <a href="next.php?id=' . $nextPage . '"> Next</a> ';
    } 
}
```

How I can do this? Some help... Thanks for advance

Answer (score 0):

To display pagination numbers you have to first count the number of pages based on the results and your page limit.

Use 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS as COUNT' column in your sql query which gets the results count. And store it in a variable, say $total_results.

Calculate the number of pages using the formula,

```
$page_count = ($total_results / $page_limit) + 1
```

Where,

```
$page_count => The number of pages available \n
$total_results => The number of result rows (from sql query COUNT)
$page_limit => Number of results shown in each page
```

In your PHP page print the HTML like this for dropdown,

```
<select id='pageNo'>
    <?php
        for($i=1; $i < $page_count; $i++) {
            echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$i."</option>";
        }
    ?>
</section>
```

In the jQuery write a change function,

```
$('#pageNo').on('change', function(){
    var loadPage = $('#pageNo').val();
    // Do your page submit to load another page
});
```

I hope this will help you. Please modify this to fit your need.

Comment: I got hard time in jquery. How I can mix it in my jquery? pardom me.

Comment: It is a independent script. You can place it anywhere in your pages javascript file.

Comment: the dropdown is right. But when I try to select nothing happens. Would you mine to explain it? I have two page. Page 1 that has a jquery to modify dynamic dropdown. The Page 2 have the SQL Query.

Comment: Did you finish the sql and php part as I specified. So, do you have the dropdown with the number of pages available in it.

Comment: please. I really need to finish this script

Comment: With the detail you provided it is a little difficult for me to understand how you are creating pages. Create a online file with your pages code i will look into it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44872/discussion-between-script-shiva-and-surname)

Comment: Helo Script Shiva let's start?

Comment: Sorry man i was busy in office, ping me when you are online. I will be online for next 10 hours.